# How can I use the for in a controller that return the PartialView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

In the razor view we can use [partial tag helper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/partial-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-3.1) `<partial />`. We pass the partial name by passing the `name` attribute in the tag helper. We can also pas the `for` attribute and it renders the form for the given value.

So, for example, I declare the partial tag helper like this, 
`<partial name="_Form.cshtml" for="ListOfObject[i]" />`

in the `_Form.cshtml` I have,

```
@model Object

<input asp-for="Debit" class="form-control">
```

Let say `i` param is **0**. Then, here is how it rendered,

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" id="ListOfObject_0__Text" name="ListOfObject[0].Text" value="">
```

I have a controller that `return PartialView("_Form.cshmtl")`. 
The controller is called with an ajax call.
My question is how can implement the `for` attribute in the controller? So, I can render the partial in correct index of `ListOfObject`.

Thank you.

Comment: You can refer to the official [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controller.partialview?view=aspnetcore-5.0),and do like what `Abhilash Augustine` posted.

Answer (score 0):

```
public IActionResult GetFormPartial(FormModel yourItem)
{
    //var form = new FormModel() { Name = "User" };
    return PartialView("_FormPartial", yourItem);
}
```

You can pass your object (`ListOfObject[i]`) to your controller as parameter and then bind this object to your partial view like above.